# Как объединить фигуры на canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, canvas

Мне нужно прикрутить графическое редактирование к текущему проекту. Не могу найти решение по обледенению фигур. Например, есть некий круг(или любая другая фигура) и некий квадрат, мне нужно объединить их (или создать новый объект такой формы).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать на canvas? Есть ли какой простой механизм, так как такие преобразования должны проходить часто? Возможно как-то получить площадь?

ЗЫ

Посоветуйте, что почитать про canvas, нахожу только основы.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'lime';
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 80, 80);

var can2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
var ctx2 = can2.getContext('2d');

ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.fillStyle = "green";
ctx2.arc(100, 60, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, 1);
ctx2.fill();

var can3 = document.getElementById('canvas3');
var ctx3 = can3.getContext('2d');

ctx3.drawImage(can, 0, 0);
ctx3.drawImage(can2, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" width="200" height="200" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: У вас на canvas3 две разные фигуры, меня интересует объедение, что бы была именно одна. Т.к. у меня будет проблемы при масштабировании элементов и т.д.